# Spring 3.2 servlet 3.0 Java Config (no web.xml) how to create custom 404 handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

What options do I have to catch and handle 404 without using `web.xml`. This is how I define my Servlet:

```
@Order(1)
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    // 10MB
    private static final int MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new SiteMeshFilter() };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_MB, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_MB * 2,
                MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE_IN_MB / 2);
        registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
    }

}
```

My application is all configured in java code, `@ControllerAdvice` works fine with all other exceptions like:

```
BindException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
MissingServletRequestPartException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class, TypeMismatchException.class
```

however

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeClass {
...
    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ResourceNotFoundException.class, NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class })
    public ModelAndView handle404() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("/errors/404");
        modelAndView.addObject("exception", "404 NOT FOUND!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
...
}
```

does NOT catch 404
I have also tried HttpStatus... without any luck

when I call /someUrlThatDoesNotExist :

```
[DEBUG] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,639 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /someUrlThatDoesNotExist reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[DEBUG] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,640 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet doService - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/someUrlThatDoesNotExist]
[DEBUG] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,641 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping getHandlerInternal - Looking up handler method for path /someUrlThatDoesNotExist
[DEBUG] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,662 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping getHandlerInternal - Did not find handler method for [/someUrlThatDoesNotExist]
[WARN] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,663 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/someUrlThatDoesNotExist] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
[DEBUG] 2014-01-24 10:03:16,665 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet processRequest - Successfully completed request
```

but when I try inspect below point-cuts using AOP:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(..)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod(..)
```

they never get caught..

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to configure your `DispatcherServlet` to throw an exception if no handler is found

```
dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```

and then have your `@ControllerAdvice` declare an `@ExceptionHandler` for an exception of type `NoHandlerFoundException`.

Comment: do you have example on how to do that with AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ?

Comment: @marcin I don't have access to code right now, but that class should have a configureDispatcherServlet() method you can override to do that.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis I think that setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound is only available in spring 4.0 not 3.2.6 dispatcherServlet

Comment: looks like 4.0 only to me. there is a protected method on dispatcher servlet that you could override called noHandlerFound. Right now it just sets the status to 404, you could throw an exception instead

Comment: @MarcinWasiluk Hadn't seen your comment. It doesn't look like you can without overriding a bunch of things in 3.2.6.

Comment: I'm trying to call setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound, but instantiate via web.xml and use WebMvcConfiguratorAdapter, not sure where to put the call myself

Comment: @MattBroekhuis Unfortunately `WebMvcConfiguratorAdapter` doesn't really have any relation to the `DispatcherServlet`. I can't find a non-programmatic way to set the property. :(

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So did you find a way of doing this in code, using Spring 3.2.x ?

Comment: @AyubMalik I have not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How to get hold of DispatcherServlet in Spring 4.0?